# How to apply Kalman Filter on RSSI values in Android?

Tags: java, algorithm, android-studio, filtering, kalman-filter

I am working on a project that calculates the distance between devices based on RSSI value received. However, the RSSI value is quite varying and I want to apply a Kalman Filter to it but I am not able to do so. The RSSI value is returned by the method `getRssi()` which returns a single value of type `int`. The Kalman Filter as I read about in various links needs an array of values but I am not sure how to make and use that array or apply the filter to it and what to do if the value is singular and of type `int`
I am relatively new to Android and Java so any input will be helpful.

Comment: To which class does this `getRssi()` method belong to? I found it in WifiInfo (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo) as well as ScanResult (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanResult). Also, how are you planning to use this value to get the distance between devices?

Comment: I am using the `ScanResult` class as I am working with Bluetooth LE. There is a direct formula for conversion of RSSI to distance which you can easily find on Google. I have made and app that scans for BLE devices nearby and also returns the RSSI of the signal. Though the RSSI values are quite varying due to noises etc. and I want to apply a Kalman Filter to it before using it to calculate the distance between the devices